# How to make my Android application work in lower version only

Tags: android

I would like my Android app to be limited to versions 1.0 to 2.3.3 - is that possible? If so, I'd also like display an alert message if the app is executed on a higher version.

Here is what I tried changing my `Manifest.xml` file to:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="1"
    android:targetSdkVersion="1"
    android:maxSdkVersion="2" />
```

Comment: 2.3.3 and 2.3.4 are API level **10**, not **2**. downvoted for **WORST PRACTICE**. You should always target the **latest** API Level. And you should put **NO LIMIT**.

Comment: @Tobor You shouldn't downvote a question because his personal app has "bad practice". He doesn't want his app to support higher versions, so what? That doesn't affect the quality of his question. His question is still a good one IMO. I did +1 your comment because of the API level part.

Comment: @Mike I just want to discourage **WORST** practices and encourage **BEST** ones. He should learn to write **QUALITY** software.

Comment: @Tobor You miss my point: this is a QnA site. Yes, it's weird for him to do what he's doing, but you're not encouraging/discouraging anything. You're just making a post look worse than it is. The downvote has nothing to do with the quality of the post, as it should. It's his business and it's not even the **WORST** practice. He's at least informing the app user that their device is too old. Maybe he has good reason to do this.

Comment: Have these answers helped you?

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
<uses-sdk
android:minSdkVersion="1"
android:targetSdkVersion="18"
android:maxSdkVersion="10" />
```

If the app isn't compatible with higher API's their shouldn't be able to install it and therefore a alert message isn't needed.
But I don't see why you should prohibit higher API's?

Answer (score 0):

Write this code onCreate() method,

```
int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;

if (currentapiVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD_MR1)
{
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sorry, Version not supported", Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
} 
else
{
    // procced further
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Android version 2.3.3 is API 10. So, this code, as an example, should work:

```
package yourPackage;

// imports

public class YourClass extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 10) { // API > 10
            Toast.makeText(this, "Android version is too old", 0).show();
        } else{ // API <= 10
            setContentView(R.layout.yourLayout);
            // do everything else in your app
        }
    }
}
```

However, Android version 2.3.4 is also API 10, so your app would have to include Android 2.3.4 as well.